# Função replace JavaScript não está funcionando

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma função em uma parte do sistema que não está funcionando. Aparece o erro `Uncaught TypeError: addPriceAddProd.replace is not a function` mas não sei o que estou fazendo de errado. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Segue meu código que faz a ação.

```
function subtrairMenos1Add<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>() {
var n1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('qtdIngredientAdicional<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>').value);
var n2 = parseInt(1);
                                                            document.getElementById('qtdIngredientAdicional<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>').value = n1 - 1;
valorInputGeneral = document.getElementById('qtdIngredientAdicional<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>').value;
orgPriceProd = document.getElementById("orgPriceProd").value;
if(valorInputGeneral < 1) {
                                                                document.getElementById('qtdIngredientAdicional<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>').value = 0;
}
if(valorInputGeneral > 0){
                                                            //if(valorInputGeneral > 0){
var priceAdicional = document.getElementById("adicionalPrice<?=$idIngredientAdicional?>").value;
                                                            //alert(priceAdicional);
var priceProd = document.getElementById("priceProd").value;
var priceProdFormatAm = priceProd.replace(",",".");

var addPriceAddProd = parseFloat(priceProdFormatAm) - parseFloat(priceAdicional);
                                                            //alert(addPriceAddProd);
//var priceProdFormatBr = addPriceAddProd.replace(".",",");
 var addPriceAddProdBr = addPriceAddProd.replace(".",",");
                                                            alert(addPriceAddProdBr);
                                                            document.getElementById("priceProd").value = addPriceAddProd;
 //}
}

if(valorInputGeneral <= 0){
                                                                document.getElementById("priceProd").value = orgPriceProd;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O resultado do [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) é um Number, e o método [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) é um método de Strings. Para fazer esse replace tens de converter o numero de volta para String.

Mas talvez não seja isso que queres fazer... se for isso então a pergunta está respondida. Se o que queres é formatar o numero no final, podes usar o [`.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) que converte numeros em String com o formato do país que passares. Por exemplo:

```js
const valor = 2354.56;
const representacao = valor.toLocaleString('pt-BR');
console.log(representacao); // 2.354,56
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!! resolveu meu problema